# Filter issue in grails

Tags: grails

My requirement is to update user session record in database on each click that hits the server.
So I have written filter for this

```
allExceptLogin(controller: 'login', invert: true){
    before = {
    }
}
```

Which works fine as it goes inside filter where I can update the record but the problem is that if I have more than 1 method calls on a single click then it goes inside this filter that many times.

For e.g. If I click on a page which calls 4 different methods from same or different controller then it will go inside this filter 4 time which will eventually update the record 4 times.

I need some condition which says 1 click = 1 request to this filter.
Is this possible or can this be achieved by any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server has no notion of "clicks", it only deals with requests.  One possible approach is to have the client send a key param with each "click" that your filter could then process in one batch.

Another option is to set a timeout on the server (e.g. on the `session` object) to only process requests every x many seconds.  You may miss some related calls as well, but that may be OK.

The short of it is that Grails itself does not have a built-in mechanism to differentiate between related requests.